# При установке transitionStyle: .scroll для UIPageViewController и возврате с другого слайда подтягиваются старые данные

Tags: swift

При установке `transitionStyle: .scroll для UIPageViewController` получаю баг при следующих шагах:

1. Запустить приложение, нажать на кнопку, задать число 10, нажать "ОК"
2. Сделать свайп вперед, нажать на кнопку, задать число 5, сделать свайп назад

На кнопке отображается число 0 (вместо числа 10).

3. Нажать на кнопку, задать число 20, нажать "ОК"
4. Сделать свайп вперед, сделать свайп назад

Новое число 20 также не отображается

С `transitionStyle: .pageCurl` этого бага нет. Что не так с моим кодом?

Мой проект: https://yadi.sk/d/A2MJf8c972Bcdw

Или вот мой код:
Файл SceneDelegate:

```
    import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.rootViewController = MainTabBarController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }
}
```

Файл MainTabBarController:

```
import UIKit

class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let firstVC = PageViewController()
        let secondVC = SecondViewController()
        
        let firstImage = UIImage(systemName: "heart")!
        let secondImage = UIImage(systemName: "circle")!
        
        viewControllers = [
            generateNavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC, title: "First", image: firstImage),
            generateNavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC, title: "Second", image: secondImage)
        ]
    }
    
    private func generateNavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController, title: String, image: UIImage) -> UIViewController {
        let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        navigationVC.tabBarItem.title = title
        navigationVC.tabBarItem.image = image
        return navigationVC
    }
}
```

Файл ModelOne:

```
    import RealmSwift

class ModelOne: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var property = "0"
    @objc dynamic var color = "green"
    
    func createModelOne() {
        if realmOne.objects(ModelOne.self).filter("color = 'green'").count == 0 {
            let newModel = ModelOne()
            newModel.color = "green"
            StorageManagerOne.saveObject(newModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Файл ModelTwo:

```
import RealmSwift

class ModelTwo: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var property = "0"
    @objc dynamic var speed = "200"
    
    func createModelTwo() {
        if realmTwo.objects(ModelTwo.self).filter("speed = '200'").count == 0 {
            let newModel = ModelTwo()
            newModel.speed = "200"
            StorageManagerTwo.saveObject(newModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Файл StorageManagerOne:

```
import RealmSwift

let realmOne = try! Realm()

class StorageManagerOne {
    static func saveObject(_ object: ModelOne) {
        try! realmOne.write {
            realmOne.add(object)
        }
    }
    static func deleteObject(_ object: ModelOne) {
        try! realmOne.write {
            realmOne.delete(object)
        }
    }
}
```

Файл StorageManagerTwo:

```
import RealmSwift

let realmTwo = try! Realm()

class StorageManagerTwo {
    static func saveObject(_ object: ModelTwo) {
        try! realmTwo.write {
            realmTwo.add(object)
        }
    }
    static func deleteObject(_ object: ModelTwo) {
        try! realmTwo.write {
            realmTwo.delete(object)
        }
    }
}
```

Файл ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let pageControl = UIPageControl()
    var currentPage = 0
    var numberOfPage = 0
    
    var valueText = ""
    let valueButton = UIButton()
    let mainView = UIView()
    
    var modelOne: ModelOne?
    var modelTwo: ModelTwo?
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        modelOne = realmOne.objects(ModelOne.self).filter("color = 'green'")[0]
        modelTwo = realmTwo.objects(ModelTwo.self).filter("speed = '200'")[0]
        configuration()
    }
    
    func configuration() {
        pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPage
        pageControl.currentPage = currentPage
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = .gray
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .blue
        
        valueButton.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        valueButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        valueButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
        valueButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        valueButton.setTitle(valueText, for: .normal)
        
        mainView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        
        mainView.addSubview(valueButton)
        self.view.addSubview(mainView)
        self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
        
        pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        valueButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            valueButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.centerXAnchor),
            valueButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            valueButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            valueButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 115),
            
            mainView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            mainView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: valueButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            
            pageControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            pageControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            pageControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            pageControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            ])
    }
    
    @objc func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
        var value: String?
        let alertEdit = UIAlertController(title: currentPage == 0 ?
                                                    "Please, add modelOne" : "Please, add modelTwo",
                                                    message: "",
                                                    preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
            let textField = alertEdit.textFields! [0]
            if (textField.text?.isEmpty == true) {
                value = "0"
            }
            else {
                value = textField.text!
            }
            if self.currentPage == 0 {
                try! realmOne.write {
                    self.modelOne!.property = value!
                    self.valueButton.setTitle(self.modelOne!.property, for: .normal)
                }
            }
            else {
                try! realmTwo.write {
                    self.modelTwo!.property = value!
                    self.valueButton.setTitle(self.modelTwo!.property, for: .normal)
                }
            }
        }
        
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { _ in }

        alertEdit.addAction(okAction)
        alertEdit.addAction(cancelAction)
        
        alertEdit.addTextField {(targetTF) in
            if self.currentPage == 0 {
                targetTF.text = self.modelOne!.property == "0" ? "" : self.modelOne!.property
            }
            else {
                targetTF.text = self.modelTwo!.property == "0" ? "" : self.modelTwo!.property
            }
            targetTF.keyboardType = .asciiCapableNumberPad
            targetTF.placeholder = "0"
        }
        self.present(alertEdit, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Файл PageViewController:

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    var listValue: [String]?
    
    override init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewController.TransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewController.NavigationOrientation, options: [UIPageViewController.OptionsKey : Any]? = nil) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        dataSource = self
        if let viewController = showViewControllerAtIndex(0) {
            setViewControllers([viewController],
                               direction: .forward,
                               animated: false,
                               completion: nil)
        }
        
    }
    
    func showViewControllerAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> ViewController? {
        
        ModelOne().createModelOne()
        let modelOne = realmOne.objects(ModelOne.self).filter("color = 'green'")[0]
        ModelTwo().createModelTwo()
        let modelTwo = realmTwo.objects(ModelTwo.self).filter("speed = '200'")[0]
        
        listValue = [modelOne.property, modelTwo.property]
        
        guard index >= 0 && index < listValue!.count else { return nil }
        let viewController = ViewController()
        viewController.valueText = listValue![index]
        viewController.currentPage = index
        viewController.numberOfPage = listValue!.count
        return viewController
    }
    

}

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var pageNumber = (viewController as! ViewController).currentPage
        pageNumber -= 1
//      var pageNumber = (viewController as! ViewController).currentPage
//      if (viewController as! ViewController).currentPage > 0 {
//        print("before \(pageNumber)")
//        pageNumber -= 1
//        }
        return showViewControllerAtIndex(pageNumber)
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var pageNumber = (viewController as! ViewController).currentPage
        pageNumber += 1
//        var pageNumber = (viewController as! ViewController).currentPage
//        if (viewController as! ViewController).currentPage == 0 {
//        print("after \(pageNumber)")
//        pageNumber += 1
//        }
        return showViewControllerAtIndex(pageNumber)
    }
}
```

Файл SecondViewController:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
```